# Easy way to convert a string that is formatted as a date into a Date object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date string that looks like this: `2014-07-21T12:55:31.513Z`. Is there some simple way to convert this to a date? I found that there is Date.parse() however that dives me milliseconds since Jan. 1st, 1970 which it doesn't look like that fits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date("2014-07-21T12:55:31.513Z")
```

You should also have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

use

```
new Date('2014-07-21T12:55:31.513Z')
```

*the ISO format*:

```
 YYYY-MM-DD
```

or

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

refer  [*Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> **Note**: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one
>   argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is
>   provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent
>   value will be adjusted. E.g.  new Date(2013,13,1) is equivalent to new
>   Date(2014,1,1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (note that the month
>   is 0-based).  Similarly for other values: new Date(2013,2,1,0,70) is
>   equivalent to new Date(2013,2,1,1,10) which both create a date for
>   2013-03-01T01:10:00.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but I would just parse the string to isolate the year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds the use the following function:

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```